# Scheduling & DST

Tags: php, time, calendar, timezone, utc

I am writing a calendar/scheduling app in PHP. Right now I take the day of the week you want the event to occur on and the time. I also ask for the timezone and adjust accordingly to get the event time in GMT.

Then I store that time as an offset from midnight of the day of the show. This is fine and works great, but what happens when I hit daylight savings time?  I'm not sure what to do when that happens.  The other problem is that not all countries have DST so I'm kind of in a bind there.

I am displaying these events on a calendar, so timing is important.

Comment: do you need to run it at the precise time or anytime as long as it is run regularly in some interval?

Comment: so day of week (not day, month and year), timezone (ppl in different timezones comparing schedule?), and dst? this is stored in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with DST is a real pain.

For future events you should store the location and the local time when the event is to occur, not the GMT time. This is because sometimes governments change when DST starts and stops (it just happened last year in the US) and the events then shift in GMT, but not in local time.

Then if you need to notify when the event is occurring, every day collect the events for the next 24-48 hrs and convert their times to GMT then. To do that, you need a location-timezone database like [this one](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm). Get the GMT offset for each location at the time of the event and use that to convert the time to GMT, then you know exactly when the event will occur.

Comment: Wow, this is way too much.  Basically its a calendar, with events occurring weekly, and this would be really hard to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are on the right track with GMT (UTC).  Use UTC as your canonical timestamp representation whenever you have some event that occurs (or has occurred) at a specific *point-in-time*.  UTC is unaffected by DST rules, so it serves as a great, unambiguous point-in-time representation.

Once you have a strategy for unambiguous representation of the event date/time, then you can pretty easily solve the problem of *localizing* date/times based on what time zone makes the most sense to accept from your users (or display to them). You probably need to know and store the time zone of the event as well, but, because you're storing the actual event date/time in UTC, you can pretty easily localize it to the time zone of the user if that is more relevant to them in any given use case.

This localization is usually performed with a time zone library either provided by your SDK (e.g. Java has java.util.Calendar) or as a third party extension (e.g. Python has pytz).  I'm sure PHP has an equivalent, but I'm not as familiar with its libraries.

These libraries are usually built on top of a rules database such as the [Olson Zoneinfo DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo). These rules can change quite frequently, so you have to stay on top of updates to the underlying database, especially if you are developing a truly global application.  However, they do a good job of externalizing the esoteric, nebulous time zone rules so that you can (in theory) update the rules database without have to perform a major upgrade of your runtime environment or make significant code changes when the DST rules in a particular area change.

It's not the easiest problem in the world and stinks that we have to do it, but once you've done it a couple times and grok the separation of concerns between storing exact point-in-time representation vs. the concern of localization, then it becomes second nature.

Comment: Any reference to guidelines, how can I parse the Olson files? I see in their readme only guidelines to compiling it somehow into unix

Comment: Why do you want to parse them? Most languages have a library or libraries that sit on top of it.  Are you writing your own library?

Comment: I got the impression that the libraries are not up to date enough. At the meanwhile I found a very decent way to keep the library (PHP) up to date, so you are right

Comment: Cool. I'm not sure how the PHP library works, but with python-dateutil, it tries to use the system zoneinfo DB before falling back to the one packaged with the library.  In that design, the zoneinfo is as current as the one distributed with the OS which is generally pretty current on Mac and Linux distros if you're keeping current with system updates.  I'm not sure about Windows or if it even ships a zoneinfo DB in which case it would fall back to its own packaged version.

Answer (score -2):

Why not pass the responsibility to the users. I assume they need to be registered in order to use the application.

Just have them say in their profile what's their time offset. Like GMT + 2, GMT - 8, etc. They would know when their DST settings changed and update their profile accordingly.

Of course, this depends on your user base. They may accept the approach or not.

Comment: Users rarely update their profiles, and it is very unlikely they would be willing to do so whenever DST starts and ends.  Users expect software to know about DST.