# Convert GMT time to Day light saving countries Timezone

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

I am working on project in which i am converting the time according to user location. i.e if user belongs to ALASKA then then all the information will be shown according to his countries timezone.I did some conversion but i am getting wrong time in case of user has a Daylight timezone (DST) which changes frequently.

Here is my code snippet.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$offset=$_SESSION['gmtoffset'];
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))-(-$offset));
```

So in this case how do i maintain this timezone? what is the exact way for this time related conversions?

Any guidance and idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting $_SESSION['gmtoffset']? Show that please. Also state the difference between the time output and the desired time output

Comment: like $_SESSION['gmtoffset']=-12000 or you can see also timezone table gmt offset field

Comment: You should drop the offset stuff and work with timezones according to the 2.x cookbook using the timezone strings/object etc. this way there is no issue here and everything works smoothly out of the box.

Comment: I don't understand, if you want to only use ALASKA's timezone why are you using UTC timezone and then adding offset instead of using ALASKA's timezone?

Comment: My server is GMT so i convert using timezone and working fine but getting veriation while DST(day light saving timezone) country in a list

Comment: Why not use javascript to set the current user's offset in a cookie and use that instead?

Comment: Yes i have that use offset in session but problem in convert that time using offset to DST(day light saving timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution

Javascript:

```
var timeZone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
document.cookie="tz=" + (timeZone/(-60));
```

Then PHP:

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['tz']) && $_COOKIE['tz']>=-12 && $_COOKIE['tz']<=13){
    $offset = $_COOKIE['tz'];
    $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $offset * 3600, true);
    if($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $offset * 3600, false);
    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
}else{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

Comment: Can i see this function timezone_name_from_abbr() so i can check and verify it is working or not ?

Comment: Can you please explain this line `$_COOKIE['tz']>=-12 && $_COOKIE['tz']<=13` ?

Comment: This is to prevent a potential non-good wisher to insert some funny stuff into the cookie that may cause any further trouble. The lowest timezone offset is -12 and the highest is 13 thus that line.

Comment: here you set default timezone as we get in $tz but i dont want to do that in my apps user simplly input data and time as per his timezone and i want to convert that time to GMT.i want to use globle logic for all the customer which have diffrent timezone on DST based timezone.

Comment: You can use time() in php it is timezone independent and will always return GMT / UTC time

Comment: User select time from dropdown not is autogenerated..and i have tested your script and getting 1:30 hours difference between actual time and generated time using scripts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30982/discussion-between-bhavik-patel-and-php-nub-qq)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you are only getting the current offset - not the full time zone.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit uncertain to what in particular you are asking, but hopefully this will help.

If your question is regarding *detecting* that the user is in the Alaska time zone, then read:

- [How to detect user's timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16525617/634824)

If your question is about picking a time zone by country, then read:

- [In PHP, how can I get Timezone from offset and country?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14589678/634824)

If you are wanting to understand Alaskan time zones, recognize that there are three different legal zones, and seven different IANA/Olson/TZ time zones (that PHP can use):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Alaska

Don't try to treat a time zone as a numeric value.  See "TimeZone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you are wanting to manipulate dates with time zones in PHP, see the example in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for `date_default_timezone_set`.

If you just want to work with UTC, then there's no reason to do anything with time zones at all.  The browser can always convert UTC to and from the user's local time zone, whatever that might be.  Just create your JavaScript `Date` objects with a UTC timestamp integer, or parse from a UTC format, such as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`.

To eliminate browser inconsistencies, you might want to use a library instead, such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
// here's one way
var m = moment('2013-05-31T12:34:56Z');

// here's another
var m = moment.utc('2013-05-31 12:34:56','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

// pretty much anything else you might want to do...
```

Comment: so this time can convert like day light timezone..?

Comment: my question is about to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563053/scheduling-dst`